# Solve a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

$\newcommand{\Sp}{\phantom{0}}$There is a system of linear equations:
\begin{alignat*}{4}
 &x -  &&y - 2&&z = &&1, \\
2&x + 3&&y -  &&z =-&&2.
\end{alignat*}

I create the matrix of the system:
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
    2 & 3 & -1 & -2
  \end{array}\right]
$$ 
then with GEM,
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
    0 & 5 & 3 & -4
  \end{array}\right]
$$

I don't know how to proceed after that?
I have found the correction of this exercise but I still don't understand the way to solve it. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Sorry, it was a 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem of finding the *complete solution* to $Ax=b$. To learn how to do this, you may want to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75Q0ZN2njGQ) or Gilbert Strang's full [video lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q1q7s1jTzU) or [notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/ax-b-and-the-four-subspaces/solving-ax-b-row-reduced-form-r/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses1.8sum.pdf) on the topic.

The idea is that we need to find

(a) the null space $N$ of $  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -1 & -2 \\
    2 & 3 & -1
  \end{array}\right]$ and

(b) a single solution $c$ to $  \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    1 & -1 & -2 \\
    2 & 3 & -1
  \end{array}\right]c =
\left[\begin{array}{r} 1 \\-2
  \end{array}\right] $.

Then all the solutions are exactly $x = N + c$.

---

Row reduction is the first step regardless of what we do next.

(a) We have $\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    1 & -1 & -2 \\
    0 & 5 & 3
  \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{r} 7/5 \\ -3/5 \\ 1 \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{r} 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$. Thus the null-space is $N = \left[\begin{array}{r} 7/5 \\ -3/5 \\ 1 \end{array}\right]a$.

(b) Notice that $ \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    1 & -1 & -2 \\
    0 & 5 & 3
  \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{r} 1/5 \\ -4/5 \\ 0 \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{r} 1 \\ -4 \end{array}\right] $.

Hence the solutions are exactly all $x$ such that

$$ x = \left[\begin{array}{r} 7/5 \\ -3/5 \\ 1 \end{array}\right]a + \left[\begin{array}{r} 1/5 \\ -4/5 \\ 0 \end{array}\right].$$

Another way of writing this is

\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{7}{5}a + \frac{1}{5} \\
y &= -\frac{3}{5}a - \frac{4}{5} \\
z &= a.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

I would apply two more row operations and present a solution with a free variable:

$$
\begin{align*}
& \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
    2 & 3 & -1 & -2
  \end{array}\right]  R_2+(-2)R_1 \rightarrow R_2 \\
\equiv & \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
    0 & 5 & 3 & -4
  \end{array}\right] \frac{1}{5}R_2 \rightarrow R_2 \\
\equiv & \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{5} & -\frac{4}{5}
  \end{array}\right]  R_1+R_2 \rightarrow R_1 \\
\equiv & \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 0 & -\frac{7}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{3}{5} & -\frac{4}{5}
  \end{array}\right].
\end{align*}
$$

Read the solution straight from the matrix as

$$
\begin{align*}
x &=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{7}{5}r \\
y&=-\frac{4}{5}-\frac{3}{5}r \\
z&=r,
\end{align*}
$$

with $r\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Bringing the matrix in reduced row echelon form $R$ (the way other answers have shown) is the first step no matter what you do.

As for "reading off" the solutions off $R$, I think there are several techniques. The one I was taught, and which I find the easiest to use, is the following:

1. remove all zero rows

In the example this leads to
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -\frac{7}{5} & | & \frac{1}{5} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{3}{5} & | & -\frac{4}{5}
\end{bmatrix}$, so nothing changed here, since there were no zero rows

2. then insert any additional zero rows so the matrix is square and the pivots are all on the diagonal

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -\frac{7}{5} & | & \frac{1}{5} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{3}{5} & | & -\frac{4}{5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & | & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

3. now you can read off a special solution $\lambda$ off the right hand side

$\lambda = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5} \\ -\frac{4}{5} \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

4. replace all zero entries on the diagonal with $-1$.

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -\frac{7}{5} & | & \frac{1}{5} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{3}{5} & | & -\frac{4}{5} \\
0 & 0 & -1 & | & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

5. the columns with $-1$ on the diagonal (the free columns) now form the basis of the null space

$N = \langle \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{7}{5} \\ \frac{3}{5} \\ -1\end{pmatrix} \rangle = \{ r\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{7}{5} \\ \frac{3}{5} \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$ }, for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

And then, of course, the complete solution is just $\lambda + N$, that is $L = \{ \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5} \\ -\frac{4}{5} \\ 0\end{pmatrix} + r\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{7}{5} \\ \frac{3}{5} \\ -1\end{pmatrix} | r \in \mathbb{R} \}$